# Dataflow BigTable read rows by prefix defined at runtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, apache-beam, dataflow, bigtable

I'm using Google Dataflow to read rows from BigTable based on row prefix and need to change the prefix between pipeline runs. I unsuccessfully tried to parameterize the scan configuration as there's apparently no way how to pass a ValueProvider to the scan configuration that would carry the runtime parameter.

Here's a code snippet of the scan config with static prefix provided:

```java
   // Scan config definition
    private static CloudBigtableScanConfiguration getCloudBigtableScanConfiguration(CatalogPipelineOptions options) {
        Scan scan = new Scan()
            .setCacheBlocks(false)
            .setFilter(
                // FIXME: How to provide the prefix at runtime/when executing the dataflow template?
                new PrefixFilter("prefix-changed-at-runtime-".getBytes())
            );

        return new CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
            .withProjectId(options.getBigtableProjectId())
            .withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId())
            .withTableId(options.getBigtableTableId())
            .withScan(scan)
            .build();
    }
  
   // Use of the scan config
    pipeline.apply("Read from BigTable", Read.from(
        CloudBigtableIO.read(getCloudBigtableScanConfiguration(options)))
    );
```

Is there a way how to pass a runtime parameter to the scan configuration and not rely on a single value defined during the pipeline build?

Comment: The scan configuration for the Dataflow-Bigtable connector does not support a parameter for runtime as https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase-api/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/beam/CloudBigtableScanConfiguration mentions. Could you expand a bit on what you are trying to achieve? Maybe there's a workaround for it

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to build a pipeline that would be configurable for what data it'll read from BigTable based on different table ID and key prefixes. The idea is that I have data for multiple application instances for different customers stored in a single table and I need to be able to specify (based on the key prefix) which data to process by the pipeline. I've also used the `BigtableIO.read().withRowFilter()` which supports a ValueProvider but it appears that the runtime parameter gets ignored and only the static one from the time of the pipeline build remains. Thank you